# Using typedef keyword in c

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef

I was going through one of the lecture slide taught in the class which included a typedef keyword in it. As opposed to normal use of typedef keyword where we usually put a alias for particular data, there was no alias put up for that example. Following is the example:[See the typedef in the slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkmLj.png)

Is the use of typedef correct, or am I interpreting differently?

Comment: `Ptr` is the alias.

Comment: If there were two function pointers with same declaration,ptr would be alias to which of the function pointers?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: A **typedef** for type-alias `foo` has the exact same syntax as a declaration of variable `foo`, of the same type, but with the reserved word `typedef` **among** the *storage class specifiers* in the declaration.

Answer (score 2):

It is a function pointer. And it is perfectly valid syntax.

`Ptr` is declared as a pointer to a function where the function takes two `int` arguments and return an `int`. Here you can use `Ptr` as the alias to the typedefed type.

Comment: @melpomene.: Thanks for the edit. Appreciate it.